# Time '12:00 AM' to be converted into timestamp

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I need the time '12:00 AM' to be converted into timestamp and I tried the strtotime() function for that. See my code below.

$eventstarttime=strtotime($_POST['eventstarttime']);

Getting a timestamp but it is not correct. I checked here, [enter link description here](http://www.epochconverter.com)

The value has 8 hours of difference. Please get me a solution to get the correct timestamp of time like 12.00 PM.

Comment: You need to provide the date too to get exact timestamp

Comment: @Thamilan `strtotime` will process `12am` as `12am today` without issues. Issue is more likely timezones.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime is filling in the date using now.

try setting your timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```